# Will a homebrew installation of mysql conflict with xampp or netbeans?

Tags: macos, mysql, homebrew

I had mysql installed on my OS-X machine via macports a while back. I think it ended up conflicting with something I used for a wordpress test site (something like XAMPP), and I wasn't able to reinstall it. I don't remember exactly what happened and I can't find my notes on it, but I remember it being a real pain.

Right now, I have netbeans and XAMPP installed. XAMPP uses it's own mysql server, as does netbeans. Do I need to worry about another mysql installation messing anything up? I really don't want to go through all the trouble I went through last time.

Comment: we really can't tell you that. yes it is always possible that a product requires a different version of a library, and the framework in use has no means to disambiguate between the two, such that when one dependency is installed, a dependency of the other program must be uninstalled. or worse, the system may confuse the two libraries. without looking closely at both pieces of software, there is always a risk. Why do you want a separate MySQL instance anyway? is it possible that in your previous iteration, that your sofware was compatible, but erased the WP config, and that's what broke it?

Comment: @FrankThomas Both of the other instances are baked into their respective programs: I want to be able to call `mysql` from my terminal and be able to start and stop the server outside of those two programs. Right now I can't do either. And when it broke a while ago, I wasn't just unable to use wordpress, I was unable to access the database via the terminal, so it didn't just erase the WP config. I guess I'll just try it and cross my fingers. Thanks for the info.